# Deleting rows in Excel VBA without Activating workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have bumped in a little problem. I want to Delete some rows with VBA, but i want to avoid using Activate or select statements. The problem is, that if i don't activate the workbook, my code returns an error when deleting or copying rows.

```
With Template.Worksheets("1").Range("A3").CurrentRegion
 rCountS = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
 .Range("A4", Cells(rCountS, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

The .Range part returns an error below:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Is there a way to avoid using activate when deleting rows in Excel?

Thank you

Comment: Not `Cells(rCount...` but `.Cells(rCount...` (dot was skipped)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Did not know it was that simple. :) I would have never figured this one one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is missing a "." in your code.
For an easier reading and adaptability, I would assign the worksheet to a variable as well:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = Template.worksheets("1")

With ws.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
    rCountS = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    .Range("A4", .Cells(rCountS, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Did not know it was that simple. :) I would have never figured this one one

Comment: You’re welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked though, so that others may find it as well :)